# Adding a foreach loop inside another array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the following array built:

```
$arr['ticket']['custom_fields'][]   =   array('id'=>$key,'value'=>$value);
```

I want to dump the contents of that array inside the following section, rather than stating each index such as `$arr['ticket']['custom_fields'][0]`. When I try a for each loop, it fails using `var_dump` or even `var_export`? Any ideas on how I might do this?

```
$create = json_encode(array('ticket' => array('subject' => $arr['z_subject'],
 'comment' => array( "body"=> $arr['z_description']), 'requester' =>
array('name' => $arr['z_name'], 'email' => $arr['z_requester']), 
'custom_fields' => array(**$arr['ticket']['custom_fields'][]**))));
```

Comment: `foreach($arr['ticket']['custom_fields'] as $array) { var_dump($array); }` or `foreach($arr['ticket']['custom_fields'] as $array) { echo $array['id'];  echo $array['value']; }`

Comment: It fails in what way? How did your failing code look like?

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH), expecting ')' is what I get when doing the for each as you suggested. it works fine by itself, but not as suggested:

Comment: I did try creating a concatenated string which kind of works to make one string dump, but would rather use the for each if possible.

    $customfields = '';
    foreach($arr['ticket']['custom_fields'] as $val) {
        $customfields .= '{"id":';
        $customfields .= var_export($val['id'], true);
    $customfields .= ",";
    $customfields .= '"value":';
    $customfields .= var_export($val['value'], true);
    $customfields .= "},";
    }